# How to find missing records from tables - MySQL compare tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables in a single database. There is one common field for each tables. The tables are named `tablea` and `tableb`. `tafa` in `tablea` and `tbfa` in `tableb` contains same data. `tableb` is generated from `tablea`, so that all rows are there in `tablea` while in `tableb`, some rows are missing. I want to display `tafa` fields, which are not present in `tableb`. The tables may look like this;

`tablea`

```
tafa | tafb   | tafc
-----------------------
1    | apple  | fruit
2    | carrot | veggie
3    | orange | fruit
4    | kiwi   | fruit
```

`tableb`

```
tbfa | tbfb   | tbfc
-----------------------
1    | apple  | fruit
2    | carrot | veggie
4    | kiwi   | fruit
```

and I want the result as;

```
3    | orange | fruit
```

How can I do this using PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This statement should give you the result you want

```
select tablea.* from tablea  left join tableb on tbfa=tafa where tbfa is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join:

```
select a.*
from tablea as a left join tableb as b on a.tafa = b.tbfa
where b.tbfa is null
```

**The explanation:**

`LEFT JOIN` will return all the values on the right-side table and only the matching values on the left-side table. Without the `where` the result would be like this:

```
select a.*, b.tbfa from tablea as a left join tableb as b on a.tafa = b.tbfa

tafa | tafb   | tafc   | tbfa
-----------------------------
1    | apple  | fruit  |  1
2    | carrot | veggie |  2
3    | orange | fruit  |  NULL
4    | kiwi   | fruit  |  4
```

All that remains is filter out the row where `tbfa` has a `NULL` value